# Miners influence

Tags: blockchain

How many people represents the bitcoin's minors? Thousands ? Hundreds ? Or just a few organization controlled by a minority of people that possess the means to run minig plants?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8kua5B5K3I

Can the price of BTC be manipulated by minors? for example if they all decide together to sell every btc the create to lower the price.

Comment: max amount of BTC : 21'000'000 - gift for mining a block 25 BTC - one block mined approximativly every 10 minutes  >>>  1'300'000 BTC mined every year - if one or a few organization mined every blocks for one year it could possess at term around 15% of total BTCs

Comment: Since all bitcoin originates as a mining reward...100% of all bitcoin in existence was at one point collected by miners.  Are you instead asking about mining centralization?

Comment: Technically... more than 100% all bitcoin in existence was collected by miners, since (1) sum of tx fees in all blocks > 0 and (2) bitcoin has no block reward penalty :P

Comment: This question is not clear at all. as others have already stated, all bitcoins originate from mining. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

How much represents the total amount of BTC collected by miners compared to the total number of BTC?

Miners collect all the Bitcoin! Some will keep it, some will set it to pay for mining equipment and energy costs. Most miners are probably somewhere in between.

In the beginning miners collected 50BTC per block (plus transaction fees) not then collest 25BTC per block. Soon the reward will drop to 12.5BTC.

Bitcoins are sold, traded and spent. Although miners initially collect all the BTC they do not own most of it in the long term because it circulates around the world to users of all types